# Multiprocessing causes Python to crash on Windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a Python program that creates a multiprocessing pool and calls a Cythonized procedure that does some heavy calculations calling `sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `tan`, `atan` from `libc.math` and doing lots of leastsq optimizations. Without multiprocessing everything works just fine.

If I use `multiprocessing.pool` on `pool.join()` all processes crash with the rather unhelpful message

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

The parent process keeps working after that, but when closing the app it crashes too.

The crash dump contains the following information

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:       APPCRASH
  Application Name:         python.exe
  Application Version:      0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    527fcf56
  Fault Module Name:        libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
  Fault Module Version:     0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4bc96cad
  Exception Code:           40000015
  Exception Offset:         00016646
  OS Version:               6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:                1033
  Additional Information 1: 9155
  Additional Information 2: 9155109303dda76ab293160797d571e1
  Additional Information 3: de56
  Additional Information 4: de566ab6f110978dbca8423195800025
```

Update: I did a separate check with calling a dummy function. It still crashes. With map, map_async, apply, apply_async. This happens only inside my program. Simple pool scripts work Ok.

The Pool code is behind the `if __name__ == '__main__':`

It looks like some "dll hell", but I'm not sure how or where to check that.

I don't think the code is of any help here as even very generic one crashes here. I can't post the whole program anyway as it contains GUI, and three separate modules.
After removing all of the main code:

```
def func1(a):
    print a

def ExtractStarData(self):
    nprocs=2

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print 'pool'
        pool = Pool(processes=nprocs)
        print 'results'
        pool.map(func1, range(100))
        print 'close'
        pool.close()
        print 'join'
        pool.join()  #crashes here
        print 'ok'
```

I forgot to mention. The code (real, not the dummy one) works on OSX but not on Win7!

Comment: I've no idea what will happen when you put `if __name__ == '__main__':` in a function. You sure this isn't an issue? How do you call `ExtractStarData`?

Comment: Some magic happened. After trying countless number of times yesterday to make it run I got frustrated, made this post and put my PC to sleep. Everything works today! And yes, I did restart my PC yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify your code a bit:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func1(a):
    print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nprocs=2
    print 'pool'
    pool = Pool(processes=nprocs)
    print 'results'
    pool.map(func1, range(10))
    print 'close'
    pool.close()
    print 'join'
    pool.join() #crashes here
    print 'ok'
```

When I run it I get mixed up output:

```
>C:\Python27\python.exe mp_debug.py
pool
results
02

13

46

57

8
9
close
join
ok
```

Is it possible that you need a [lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) on your function, `func1`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem reappeared and I did a more thorough investigation. I was able to trace down the problem to mingw32 compiler used for compilation of cython module. After installing Microsoft VC++ for Python 2.7 and setting it as a default compiler everything went back to normal.
Here is a link to the compiler:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer?  I compiled a C extension using mingw32 and now I'm having the same problem using it with multiprocessing.  I normally use the tools that come with MinGW/MSYS, like make, for instance.  Now that I need to use the Microsoft VC++ compiler, what do I do?